# Cannot find module '@electron/remote' in electron-forge pacakge

Tags: electron, electron-forge

In main precess

```
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
require('@electron/remote/main').enable(mainWin.webContents)
```

In renderer process

```
const remote = window.require('@electron/remote')
```

When running the app build with electron-forge, I got an error that is "Cannot find module'@electron/remote'".
And successfully run in dev mode.

Electron client and Vue3 UI codes in:
https://github.com/aaronchen2k/deeptest/client
https://github.com/aaronchen2k/deeptest/ui

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by add below codes in forge.config.js like https://github.com/aaronchen2k/deeptest/blob/main/client/forge.config.js:

```
[
    "@timfish/forge-externals-plugin",
    {
        "externals": ["@electron/remote"],
        "includeDeps": true
    }
]
```